# ERROR TypeError: "this.selectedExpertiseCheckBox.forEach is not a function"

Tags: angular6

I'm trying to show the list of strings on an Array after using **localStorage**.

```
radioCheckedExpertise(id, i, exp)
{
    let listing: Array<String> = [];

    listing.push(exp.name);

    listing.forEach((expLibelle: String) =>
    {
        console.log("--------------Before: " + expLibelle);
    });

    localStorage.setItem("explib", JSON.stringify(listing));
    this.selectedExpertiseCheckBox = localStorage.getItem("explib");

    this.selectedExpertiseCheckBox.forEach((expLibelle: String) =>
    {
        console.log("--------------After: " + expLibelle);
    });
}
```

But that produces:

> --------------Before: SpringBoot
>   ERROR TypeError: "this.selectedExpertiseCheckBox.forEach is not a function"

As displayed:

- I got the correct answer on the first console (Before).
- I got the wrong answer on the second console (After).

Have you please any idea about solving that issue ?.
Big thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names"));

this.selectedExpertiseCheckBox.forEach((expLibelle: String) =>
        {
            console.log("--------------After: " + expLibelle);
        });
```

HTH